# Do group actions on smooth algebraic varieties induce group actions on K-theory?

Tags: representation-theory, k-theory

(Edited after discussion in comments):

If a group $G$ acts on a smooth algebraic variety $V$, then the cohomology ring $H^*(V;\mathbb C)$ is a representation of $G$. If, furthermore, $V$ admits a stratification by affines, then the associated graded $\mathrm{gr}K(V)$ of the Grothendieck ring of $V$ is isomorphic to $H^*(V)$. Thus, one has a representation of $G$ on a filtered vector space $K(V)\otimes\mathbb C$ whose associated graded is the representation $H^*(V;\mathbb C)$.

What happens for sheaf cohomology $H^*(V;\mathscr F)$? If $\mathscr F$ has a $G$-equivariant structure then $H^*(V;\mathscr F)$ is a representation of $G$. Is there a "$K$-theoretic upgrade", i.e. a representation on a filtered vector space $K$ whose associated graded is $H^*(V;\mathscr F)$?

Comment: What is your question? K-theory is a functor, so $G$ acts on the K-theory of $V$. No freeness assumption is necessary. For sheaf cohomology you need the sheaf to have a $G$-equivariant structure to get an action of $G$ on its cohomology. What do you mean by "K-theoretic upgrade"?

Comment: I have a vague understanding that K-theory "knows more" than cohomology, and that "forgetting" K-theory structure amounts to taking the associated graded of a certain filtration. By K-theoretic upgrade I guess I want a $G$-rep of a filtered vector space whose associated graded is the cohomology as a $G$-rep. Will edit the question to reflect this -- thanks for your answer

Comment: $G$ acts on K-theory and this action is compatible with the Chern character (the Chern character is a natural transformation even when it isn't an isomorphism). Is that enough for your purposes? Unfortunately I don't know anything about filtrations on K-theory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will have to think more; probably my question isn't super well posed. FWIW, I think the filtration on $K$ should be "the $i$-th piece consists of those vector bundles whose support has dimension at most $i$", and I've seen it called the "topological filtration".

Comment: Well, the action of $G$ certainly preserves that filtration so passes to the associated graded. I don't know what the associated graded is.

Comment: Aha, I now realize that the missing piece is that the associated graded of the Grothendieck group for the topological filtration equals the cohomology. This is not true in general, but holds for the example I had in mind. In general one has a surjective morphism $A_*(V) \to \mathrm{gr}K_0(V)$ which is an isomorphism over the rationals if $V$ is nonsingular. In my examples $V$ admits a stratification by affines (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/151341/for-which-varieties-is-the-natural-map-from-the-chow-ring-to-integral-cohomology) so the Chow ring is torsionfree and isomorphic to cohomology.